# How to Check Given Date is Greater than 1 year from current Date using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, arrays, object

How to Check Given Date is Greater than 1 year using JavaScript

```
var GivenDate = '2022-07-24';
var CurrentDate = new Date();
GivenDate = new Date(GivenDate);

if(GivenDate > CurrentDate){
    console.log("true");
    alert('Given date is greater than the 1 year date.');
}else{
    console.log("false");
    alert('Given date is not greater than 1 year date.');
}
```

Comment: Use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setFullYear` to get the date one year from now:

```
const now = new Date();
const oneYearFromNow = now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 1);
```

For date comparison, a simple comparison operator works, as you did.

So, to answer your question, you can first calculate the date one year from now and compare it with the given date:

```js
const givenDate = new Date('2024-05-01');
const now = new Date();
const oneYearFromNow = now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 1);

if (givenDate > oneYearFromNow) {
  console.log('Given date is greater than the 1 year date.');
} else {
  console.log('Given date is not greater than the 1 year date.');
}
```